# Writing a simple group by with map-reduce (Couchbase)

Tags: mapreduce, nosql, couchbase

I'm new to the whole map-reduce concept, and i'm trying to perform a simple map-reduce function.

I'm currently working with Couchbase server as my NoSQL db.

I want to get a list of all my types:

```
key: 1, value: null
key: 2, value: null
key: 3, value: null
```

Here are my documents:

```
{
   "type": "1",
   "value": "1"
}

{
   "type": "2",
   "value": "2"
}

{
   "type": "3",
   "value": "3"
}

{
   "type": "1",
   "value": "4"
}
```

What I've been trying to do is:
Write a map function:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  emit(doc.type, 0);
}
```

Using built-in reduce function:

```
_count
```

But i'm not getting the expected result.

How can I get all types ?

**UPDATE**

Please notice that the types are different documents, and I know that reduce works on a document and doesn't executes outside of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default it will reduce all key groups. The feature you want is called `group_level`:

This is equivalent of `reduce=true`

```
~ $ curl 'http://localhost:8092/so/_design/dev_test/_view/test?group_level=0'
{"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":4}
]
}
```

But here is how you can get reduction by the first level of the key

```
~ $ curl 'http://localhost:8092/so/_design/dev_test/_view/test?group_level=1'
{"rows":[
{"key":"1","value":2},
{"key":"2","value":1},
{"key":"3","value":1}
]
}
```

There is also blog post about this: http://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-grouplevel-view-queries-compound-keys

There is appropriate option in couchbase admin console:
[image: group_level option in couchbase admin console]

Comment: +1 for pointing out the filter/grouping menu behind that arrow.  I had no idea that existed!