# Couchbase Map/Reduce to count total by document type

Tags: mapreduce, couchbase

I'm storing event data in Couchbase documents like this:

```
{ 
  user: {
    id: '0BE2DA2B-9C8F-432D-88C2-B2C1D8D0E4B4',
    device: { 'manufacturer': 'Apple', 'os': 'iOS', 'name': 'iPhone', 'version': '5S' }
  },
  event_type: 'INTERACTION_A',
  country: 'GB',
  timestamp: 1398781631233
}
```

I have created Map/Reduce queries to tell me how many events iPhone users have submitted. However, is it possible to use Map/Reduce to query how many unique devices by OS are submitting events?

Each individual device might have submitted 1000s of events, but the result would show how many unique devices, by OS, the system has seen. I'm trying to end up with a data that looks something like this:

```
{ 'iOS': 2343, 'Android': 6343 }
```

Is it possible to do this in a single Couchbase view?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. You just need to use `group=true&group_level=1` in your query.

Create a view like:

```
map : function(){
  emit(doc.os, null);
}

reduce: _count
```

Then add `group=true&group_level=1` to your query:

`http://127.0.0.1:8092/default/_design/dev_<designDocName>/_view/<viewName>?connection_timeout=60000&limit=10&skip=0&group=true&group_level=1`

Also check this links for more examples:

[Writing a simple group by with map-reduce (Couchbase)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505279/writing-a-simple-group-by-with-map-reduce-couchbase)

http://hardlifeofapo.com/basic-couchbase-querying-for-sql-people/

http://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-grouplevel-view-queries-compound-keys

Comment: I don't think that does what I want. My understanding (from what I can see running that on my data set) is that it will tell me how many events we've seen for each OS. What I'm trying to find is the number of discrete devices by OS

Comment: @edlea If you add the device into the key – `emit([doc.user.device.os,doc.user.id], null)` – and call the view with `group=true`, you will get unique devices per OS. Then you will be able to  count them in a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

I think my original question might have been too vague. However, I have reached this solution:

```
map: function (doc, meta) {
       emit([doc.user.device.os, doc.user.id], null);
     }

reduce: function (keys, values, rereduce) {
          var os = {};
          keys.forEach(function (k) { os[k] = 1; });
          return Object.keys(os).length;
        }
```

Running this view with group=true&group_level=1 gives me what I wanted.

I'm not confident it will scale, or whether it needs to consider rereduce, however it works for my test data set.